# Titan Stats for java GAE

Tags: google-app-engine

Is there any app with Java support similar to Titan

for monitoring the server side statistics?

http://code.google.com/p/titan-files/wiki/GettingStarted

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Try [appstats](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/appstats). Also [available for Python](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/appstats). Another helpful resource for appstats is this [recorded presentation](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bvp7CuBWVgA) by Guido Van Rossum at Google I/O 2010.